# Can I use pointer arithmetic on pointers to void pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I know you can't utilize pointer arithmetic on void pointers, but could you theoretically do pointer arithmetic on pointers to void pointers, since `sizeof(void *)` would yield an answer of how many bytes a pointer takes on your system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is not permitted on `void*` because `void` is an incomplete object type.

From C Committee draft N1570:

> **6.5.6 Additive operators**
>   ...
>   2. For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or **one operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type** and the other shall have integer type.

But it is permitted on `void**` because `void*` is NOT an incomplete object type. It is like a pointer to a character type.

> **6.2.5 Types**
>   ...
>   19. The **void type** comprises an empty set of values; **it is an incomplete object type** that cannot be completed.
>   ...
>   28. **A pointer to void** shall have the same representation and alignment requirements **as a
>   pointer to a character type**.

Comment: The second quote is not really relevant; the rules for pointer arithmetic to complete types apply

Comment: Just wanted to show that a pointer to void is a complete type.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, pointer arithmetic works on pointers to void pointers (`void**`). Only `void*` is special, `void**` isn't.

Example:

```
void *arrayOfVoidPtr[10];
void **second = &arrayOfVoidPtr[1];
void **fifth = second + 3; // pointer arithmetic
```

Comment: Some compilers allow as an extension `void *` arithmetics. One of the examples is gcc