# How are "void*" pointer declaration and "void" keyword related during memory allocation?

Tags: c

Since a C pointer returns a "void*", and in addition to its own address it might refers somehow to the memory size reserved by malloc(size), i ask myself if declaration of "void*" is actually something completely unrelated to the type "void" used to execute procedures and if "void*" is actually a kind of type that self contain informations like the allocated memory block size, with an "internal" structure similar to the one showed below.

```
//An imaginary internal implementation of "type" void* used to create pointers

struct void*
{
    char[4] address; //for 32bit systems;
    int size; //memory block size;
};

void* ptr=malloc(10); //create a pointer called ptr of 10 bytes
```

Comment: A `void*` is a pointer, like any other pointer. Thus it behaves like other pointers, not like `void`. One thing to note is that you can't do pointer arithmetic on it because that depends on the size of what it's pointing to, and you can't do that with `void`.

Comment: *"and in addition to its own address must refers somehow to the memory size reserved by malloc(size)"* - That's quite an extrapolation you make

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, since if your code is `void* ptr=malloc(10)` - it can only be C, that implicit conversion to `void*` does not exist in C++.

Comment: @StoryTeller; You wrecked my answer (which isn't one of my best anyway) ;- although you make a good point.

Comment: @Bathsheba - That second paragraph didn't do your answer any favors anyway :P

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ouch. I needed a boost today too.

Comment: @Blaze: Pointer Arithmetic is exactly the reason why i begin to think about the internal implementation of void* type and so what is the difference between void and void* beside the semantics that is clear.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I know but actually its the only imaginary construction of a pointer in the system memory. Since i have no idea how is a pointer implemented in memory, i guessed it is a kind of struct. I am very happy to discover how is pointer actually implemented in system memory.

Comment: @Paolo: Restricting my comment to Intel chips, they don't have pointers. Just registers.

Comment: It doesn't matter how a pointer is implemented. `malloc` doesn't have to rely on `void*` storing the size of the object. That's what I meant by you extrapolating here. Yes, the size must be known, but it's quite a leap to assume the pointer itself must hold it somehow.

Comment: The key is to separate the keyword `void` (used to indicate that a function takes no parameters or provides no return) and the pointer `void*` which is just a pointer than can represent any type but cannot be deferenced without having been cast to an appropriate type first..

Comment: @Paolo: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195836/can-i-use-pointer-arithmetic-on-pointers-to-void-pointers/52196548#52196548

Answer (score 5):

The use of the keyword `void` may indeed have a different semantic depending on the context:

- It can mean *nothing* such as in `void myfunction(...) { ... }` or in `int my_other_function(void) {...}`
- It can mean *anything* such as in `void *p = ...;`

In C a void pointer is a pointer that can point to anything.  In C++ as well, but the usage should be avoided as much as possible and [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) should be preferred.

Important remark about your imaginary implementation:  a void pointer does not istself know anything about the size of the object it points to.

Comment: `std::any` in C ain't gonna end well. Also you might want to mention the use of `void` as the single parameter in a function prototype, e.g. `int foo(void)`.

Comment: @Bathsheba indeed ! `f(void)` is another example for *nothing*.

Comment: I leave the `std::any`is there only because when I answered, the question was still labeled C/C++

Comment: Unless you're a Time Lord, @StoryTeller 's edit was made 4 minutes before this answer went up. Just sayin'

Comment: "Important remark about your imaginary implementation: a void pointer does not itself know anything about the size of the object it points to." Great :):).

Comment: @Bathsheba  when I read the question and started typing the answer, believe me or not, the label was there, and I did not get a refresh until I posted it. That’s not time lord logic but simple transactional consistency ;-)

Comment: @Paolo I cannot see if your comment is genuine or ironic. I made this remark because OP provided a piece of code where he imagined an implementation of a void pointer using an address *and* a size, which might suggest a misconception.

Comment: @Christophe Was genuine, in fact is a relief that a void pointer is just a pointer and nothing else. Though, this let me a little lost in understanding who "holds" the size of the memory block in order to be able to make pointer arithmetics (i hope to not make anybody disgusted with this sentence).Annti Haapala below gave some good hints about the type void and in fact maybe my question is wrongly posed since does not exist a void* type but does exist a pointer to a type "void" that is said to be an "an empty set of values" and that "it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed".

Comment: @Paolo But why do you think you need to know "size of the memory block" to do pointer arithmetic on a pointer to that block?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat suppose i define (in visual c++)   "int *ptr =(int*)malloc(10)" so to create a pointer named ptr that refers to its address and 10bytes forward. If i executes ptr++, the program will point 4 bytes forward (still in the reserved memory of 10bytes). Since ptr it's just a pointer (4byte in 32bit sys), I don't understand if the information how to increment itself, and how big is the memory reserved, are data stored in the program/data memory or if they are information used by the compiler and later lost. I don't wish to claim any true, it's just that i don't get the "mechanics".

Comment: @Paolo *"information how to increment"* Information on how to increment a pointer is determined at compilation time, not runtime (it affects generated code; otherwise it's not necessary to store it anywhere at runtime); it's determined from the pointer *type*. I.e. `int *ptr` is always incremented in 4-byte steps (if `sizeof(int) == 4`), no matter what you assign to it. And `void *ptr` can't be incremented at all, again no matter what you assign to it.

Comment: *"and how big is the memory reserved"* This information might be useful only for `free`; if `free` needs it, then it's probably stored near the `malloc`ed block. It's an implementation detail of `malloc`/`free` that you shouldn't worry about.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you for these brilliant explanations about void pointer arithmetics and the clean delineation with the malloc/free.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat & Everybody: Thanks for such interesting morning discussion! :)

Comment: @Paolo Thanks for your interesting question that raised all these constructive exchanges

Answer (score 2):

`void` has more than one use; that's all. `void` and `void*` are very different beasts. Note that `void*` is **not** a keyword, but `void` is.

Don't think of a `void*` as being your structure. It's merely a pointer that's been converted from another type by a cast. `malloc` returns a `void*` that's convertible to another pointer type by a mechanism that somewhat paradoxically makes it impossible to write `malloc` in portable C.

Comment: "malloc returns a void* that's convertible to another pointer type". So actually what is void* in sytem memory? is struct, a class (i doubt since we speak in C), some stuff that is never exposed to the language...i have no idea how a pointer is actually implemented since beside its address, also keep the memory size information...

Comment: @Paolo: `void*` is merely a pointer without type information.

Comment: @Paolo The content of a pointer variable is only an address, no extra information about the size of a memory block. It's up to the memory manager to keep track of allocated blocks but this is not stored in the pointer variable.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not completely unrelated. `void` is a type that ([C11 6.2.5p19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p19))

> comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that cannot be completed.

And `void *` is a pointer type that points to an object of the said type.

Any object pointer type can be converted to another object pointer type with an *explicit cast*, given that the pointer is suitably aligned; the only conversion between pointer types that can happen *without* a cast in C are conversions to `void *` and back again; hence the `void *` status as the generic pointer type.

The `void` type in itself can be used for other tasks - for example an expression can be cast to `void` to signal that the value is being deliberately ignored, or used as the return value type to signal that the function does not return a value. The only semantic overload is the use of `void` in a prototype: `int func(void)`  to signal that the function does not take any arguments.

Comment: Very interesting explanation. So in general a Type is meant to be a "set of values" stored somewhere in memory that selfdescribe itself? What do you mean for "given that the pointer is suitably aligned"?
According to your explanation, the title of my post should be changed in order to clarify that void* is not a type...but i don't know how to edit the question in order to give means to all the answers and comments actually provided.

Comment: @Paolo no, a type means a set of possible values of which an object of the given type can hold *one* at any given instance.

Answer (score 1):

`void* ptr=malloc(10);` creates 10 bytes of raw, uninitialised data on the heap. That data does not at this point have a type.

It does *not* "create a pointer called ptr of 10 bytes". The variable `ptr` is of `sizeof(void*)` bytes and allocated as "automatic storage" (likely on the stack), regardless of where you let it point.

See [A program uses different regions of memory for static objects, automatic objects, and dynamically allocated objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855916/584518) for an explanation of where different variables are likely allocated on mainstream computers.