# Making pointer from memory address

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I'm working on writing a memory allocator and I'm trying to store the address of the next free block in the header of the previous free block. In order to access the address of the next free block I need to convert 4 bytes in memory to a pointer. What would the best way to do so?

I've tried creating a pointer to an unsigned int and then setting the address of a pointer to the value of said int, but that did not work...

```
// address where the address to the next free block is stored
void *next_addr(void *ptr){
    return ptr-4;
}

// address to next free block
void *next_free(void *ptr){
    unsigned int *nxt = next_addr(ptr);
    return (void *) *nxt;
}
```

Comment: `4 bits`  or at least `4bytes` on 32 bit machine?

Comment: Firstly it is not legal to do pointer arithmetic on a `void*` type, because its data size is unknown, and secondly, it is undefined behaviour to do pointer arithmetic such that the new value is outside the range of addresses occupied by the object it points to (except one element past in the case of an array).

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, meant 4 bytes.

Comment: Related:[Can I use pointer arithmetic on pointers to void pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195836/can-i-use-pointer-arithmetic-on-pointers-to-void-pointers)

Comment: If you are serious about implementing a memory allocator, you may want to look at the [awkwardly written, but good basic malloc introduction](https://github.com/zyfjeff/C-HOW-TO/blob/master/c-malloc/Malloc_tutorial.pdf). It is a 32-bit implementation, but you can extend it carefully.

Comment: So before I was using UINT pointers, but it was giving me errors. Avoiding arithmatic on void pointers makes sense. But is there any way to make the return statement work, or is the unsafe behavior just not allowed by C?

Comment: What 4 bytes in memory? This code takes a pointer, converts it to another pointer, accesses the contents of that memory area, then converts those contents to another pointer. None which makes any sense to me.

Comment: It takes in a pointer to an allocated block of memory, decrements it by 4 to get to the start of the pointer of the next block and tries to convert that to a pointer. I am storing the pointer to the next block in the header of the current block, but I do not know how to access it.

Comment: The problem is your `ptr` must be associated with other data providing the size of the current block, etc.. This is generally done by using a `stuct` which provides a method for referencing next block by using a character array of size 1 as the final member in the struct. This is explained well in the pdf.

Comment: @David "...to get to the start of the pointer of the next block and tries to convert that to a pointer"  But it is already a pointer. Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin "by using a character array of size 1 as the final member in the struct" Eww, the struct hack is obsolete since 20 years, don't do that. Use flexible array members.

Comment: Except the fact that `ptr-4` shouldn't work on void pointers - you should use char pointer - what exactly did not work with your code ? Any compiling error or else ?

Comment: Agreed, but it is less hackish in the intent is to define an array that lies completely within the struct. An array[1] is the smallest that fits the bill. A FAM would would work as far as the address of the FAM is concerned.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin From the pdf it does seem that they want to create a flexible array member (they want a zero size array), but the author is not familiar with the concept of FAM.

Comment: Yes, it was awkwardly written back when 32-bit was the game and before FAM appeared (or the author caught wind of it). The FAM would provide a pointer that lies completely in the array and the pointer needed to mark the end of the metadata. The only twist would be if a FAM actually provided a pointer and not an array of length 1. Then instead of a 1-byte array converted to a pointer you would have an 8-byte pointer. I'll have to dig into that one unless you know whether the FAM is considered from a storage standpoint as a zero length array or a regular pointer that can be used as the FAM.